# fit_transform and inverse_transform on two different scripts

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

How to `fit_transform` & `inverse_transform` in separate scripts?

I first normalize numerical targets (integers) in a script.
Then, I use an other script to predict in real-time these numerical targets (regression).

`fit_transform` & `inverse_transform` functions def are in a third script.

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0.,1.))

def normalize(array):
    array = scaler.fit_transform(array).flatten()
    return array

def inverse_norm(array):
    array = scaler.inverse_transform(array).flatten()
    return array
```

Naively, I just "inverse_transformed" the predicted values within my real-time script.
But predicted values were not in the range as the original numerical targets: these are little float numbers.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed myself the problem thanks to mattOrNothing.
Just write down the answer.

First script:

```
myNormalizedArray = (myArray - myArrayMin) / (myArrayMax - myArrayMin)
```

Second script:

```
myDenormalizedArray = myPredicedArray * (myArrayMax - myArrayMin) + myArrayMin
```

Where `myArray` & `myPredicedArray` are numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In general I think you don't want to normalize you target variable but if you want to do so you can use a [label encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) instead of a minmax scaler which is rather use to normalize features

Comment: Those numerical values are not labels. I added some details to avoid further misunderstandings.

Comment: If you are normalizing discretes targets variables and then after your prediction you want to reverse back to the initial scale you can try to get the scale's coeffient from scaler.scale_, then you want to multiply it with the predicted values

Comment: It would be y_pred_unscaled = y_pred / scaler._scale, assuming y_pred is a numpy array and scaler is the scaler you used to normalize your initial array

Comment: I am trying out your solution and will get back to you in a few hours to tell.

Comment: Great, it works! (I cannot upvote unfortunately)